# Does thrift on Mono support SSL?

Tags: .net, ssl, mono, thrift

I'm having trouble finding any information WRT the above.  I am building a suite of Thrift services on Mono that I would like to secure with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

The TStreamTransport should do it. There are SSL stream implementations in both worlds, for Mono see [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography).